# macchanger: Too many open files in system

Tags: mac-address

I'm having a problem with `macchanger`.

Whenever I try to run the command `macchanger -r eth1`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Can't change MAC: interface up or not permission: Too many open files in system
```

I'm running this command as root, and the `ulimit` is set to **unlimited**.

What can I do to avoid this error?

Comment: On what operating system (if Linux, what distribution)? Does `ifconfig hw ether uu:vv:ww:xx:yy:zz` work?

Comment: I'm using Linux (Fedora 15), and the `ifconfig` and `ip` commands give the same **Too many open files in system** error.

Comment: is `ulimit -n` set to unlimited?  check with `ulimit -a`

Answer (score 2):

Everything in Linux is a file (even a small process like `macchanger`). Therefore if you already have lots of processes running, its very possible that you've reached the limit of files your system can manage.

Here's a good article on [Linux scalability](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/condor/condorg/linux_scalability.html)