# Can't change MAC address: Too many open files in system

Tags: linux, networking, security

Well, this is a old and unsolved problem in various linux communities and deserve it solves. Basically because is a important feature, these days privacy and security is a fundamental skill for everybody, and because Linux systems needs be strong and efficient, and a problem unsolved is a annoying situation.

When try change MAC address the next error message appears: **Too many open files in system**.

**Attempt 1:** I try change MAC address of my wifi card (with cable connection no problems) with `macchanger` (version 1.7.0 on Debian 10). I type the next steps:

- `sudo ip link set wlp3s0 down` (Turn off network connection)
- `sudo macchanger -a wlp3s0` (Change MAC address)
- `[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Too many open files in system` (Error message)

I've tried [another variation](https://askubuntu.com/a/276068) that involve stopping network-manager service but nothing happens.

**Attempt 2:** Trying change the MAC address with only `ip` command (steps take from [arch's wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing)):

- `sudo ip link set dev wlp3s0 down` (Turn off network connection)
- `sudo ip link set dev wlp3s0 address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` (Set custom MAC address, replace XX with numbers)
- `RTNETLINK answers: Too many open files in system` (Error message)

Various forums of linux communites have a entry (or many) about this error message (e.g [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247583/how-to-change-mac-of-wlan0), [unix&linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24177/macchanger-too-many-open-files-in-system), [archlinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200251), [macchanger's official repo](https://github.com/alobbs/macchanger/issues/31) ) and **until now don't have a clear and concise answer**.

Comment: So is your chipset a broadcom? Something else?

Comment: Yes, I have a Broadcom chipset. Is there a problem with broadcom chipsets and macchanger?